# Position fixed elements to stick the edges of their sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make two fixed elements stay with their sibling element.

```
<div class="left-img"> IMAGE HERE </div>  <!-- fixed positioned -->
<div class="container"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
<div class="right-img"> IMAGE HERE </div> <!-- fixed positioned -->
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74zUm/4/)**. So far I set:

```
top: 50%;
```

To center it vertically. But when the window re sizes horizontally the fixed elements are need to stay with their sibling, the container. How in jQuery or CSS can I do this?

I thought about doing something like

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('img').css("right", /*size here*/);

  $('.right-side-img');
})
```

But I'm not sure how I would set the window size. I'm using bootstrap so all my content is in the container and I would like to set an image to stay in the middle on the outside of each side.

Comment: `top: 50%` doesn't center vertically. It simply offsets the `top` (of the element) by 50% of the container's height. If your container's height is 1000px and your image's height is 100px, setting `top: 50%` will leave a 500px gap on the top and a 400px gap on the bottom.

Comment: I want the positions of the side images to remain fixed on the screen scrolling vertically but still attached to the container so that when you grow the window horizontally they they stay connected to the sides. So setting it to 50% and then making a margin-bottom of the negative half of element height will center the element on your screen. Its just getting the horizontal peice.

Comment: Fiddle added better showing why it needs to be fixed and the problem occurs when resizing the window horrizontally

Comment: You can give both elements the same margin as your container has? You container is 70% of width, so you have a 15% margin-left and right. Just give both images a margin. I'm not sure if I understand the question perfectly, but if I'm right this is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/74zUm/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that by setting an explicit width of the left and right absolutely positioned elements and using a proper value for `left`/`right` properties.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/74zUm/5/)**.

```css
.left-img,
.right-img{
    position: fixed;
    background: blue;
    top: 50%;   /*    <------ 15% ----->   */
    width: 12%; /* =  ((100% - 70%) / 2) - 3%
                         |      |     |    |
    width of the body  ---      |     |    --- needed gap for left/right (*)
    width of the container  -----     ----- get remaining width for each side */
}

.left-img { left: 3%; } /* (*) The gap between edges of the page and elements */
.right-img{ right: 3%; }
```

---

For unequal widths you could use CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in order to calculate the needed value for `left` and `right` properties depending on the `width` of each fixed positioned element.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/74zUm/10/)**

```css
.left-img {
    width: 150px;
    left: calc(15% - 150px);
}

.right-img{
    width: 100px;
    right: calc(15% - 100px);
}
```

It's worth noting that `calc()` [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility).

---

<sub>Here is [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22503797/1) which seems to be under a misunderstanding</sub>

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I wish I understood more about why it works but I'll take it

Comment: Better to say `For unequal/fixed widths` though.